# Problem using js file in typescript project. Angular CLI

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular-cli

I found a great github project and I was hoping to use it in my project. I'm sure I'm going to run into this problem again. So I'm really hoping I can get help on this. The project is located in the URL: https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief. I am trying to import the js file **color-thief.js** into my project and use it in a TS file or component. I added the file to my **scripts[]** in the **angular.json** file. Yet I'm still running into problems accessing the method **getColor()**. I am using intelliJ. I can't get the intellisense or code-completion to work. Which is furthermore making me think I'm not importing the file correctly.

Here is my ts file.

```
declare var ColorThief: any;
```

The path to get to the js file is

'../../js/color-thief.js'

Environmental setup is a nightmare.

Comment: use console.log(ColorThief) to see if it's properly imported. Your problem is with intellisense not with angular.

Comment: Says ColorThief is not defined.

Comment: I just want to reproduce what lokesh is doing in his readme.md file on github :|

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in your angular.json file, the script property set something like this.

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/[packageName]/js/color-thief.js",
],
```

remember to set node_modules and in the script, and import the proper .js file when that global variable is defined.

As far as i can see you need to create that object, according to color-thief package. Like this.

```
 let colorThief = new ColorThief();
```

Comment: So originally I just installed the file "color-thief.js". This time I npm installed the git project. And used  your suggestion. Now when typing console.log(ColorThief) I get f(){}. So it seems it is sort of working? But, now I'm receiving the error that getColor is undefined.

Comment: Now you're properly importing. I've edited the answer. It seems you need to create ColorThief object

Comment: idk... now I'm getting this error:     ERROR TypeError: _js_color_thief_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8___default.a is not a constructor

Comment: Honestly, I'm sure there's a solution. But, I switched to a different git project that has a better readme and seems to have a bigger following.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50909276/angular-5-get-colors-from-an-image

node-vibrant

Comment: let me test it.